Can not write data to Amazon S3
I use very simple function to write file to AWS
function writeToS3(filePath, data) {
  try {
    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    s3.config.update({ accessKeyId: process.env.AWSACCESSKEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWSSECRET });
   var params = {
     Body: String(data),
     Bucket: process.env.AWSBUCKET,
     Key: filePath,
   };
   s3.upload(params, async function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
       console.error(err, err.stack);
      } else {
       console.log(`Uploading ${data}succesfully`)
       return data;
      }
   });
 } catch (ex) {
   console.error(`S3 ${filePath} error ${ex.message}.`);
   return null;
  }
}
module.exports = { readFromS3, writeToS3 };

Function working, I see 'data' object on debugger, but really file on bucket missing, I call this function
let Aws = require('../util/s3service')
Aws.writeToS3("/file1", "hello world")

There is successful log
Uploading [object Object]succesfully

I check file present or now with WinSCP and file missing. There is no any error, all right present, but file in bucket missing, what going wrong?

Not sure if this is causing the problem, but Keys (filenames) in S3 should NOT start with a slash, so change /file1 into just file1.

@JohnRotenstein, yes, you right, this is Amazon bug, to produce NO ANY ERROR if filename start with "/". Please write down your advice as solution.

hi @Alex-1999, why your frustration is understandable, this is not a bug, as your file path is a key, so basically what you are doing is creating a / folder, then creating the file inside the / folder, maybe you could check for the / folder.

@LUKASESTEBANGUTIÉRREZ, it's a clear bug - to finish my request to AWS service without any warning or error message and without any result what I required from AWS. Its a sign of extremely low quality code, sign that AWS service not testing and some function can disappear without any return value, without doing anything and without any warning.

In Amazon S3, object Keys (filenames) should NOT start with a slash (/).
Therefore, try changing /file1 into file1.
Rather than generating an error, with the slash at the front it is probably trying to create a 'folder' with no name. It would probably have been visible via aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name//, which shows the inside of the / folder.
